# Creating a Sub-User for Main User | Linux | Permissions 

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssh, redhat

I am trying to find out how to create ssh users that can work inside my sites directories but not have complete access except for the folders I specify.

The only issue is that I need the sub-users not to create privledge issues.  It's like I want a site owner to act like root when it deals with anything in his site folder, created by him or the other workers.

Any suggestions on a stable solution?

Thanks

Comment: did you look at [chroot environments](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec296.html)?

Comment: not really needing that much.  the problem I am having now is that I created a home directory for the user, then created links to the folders I want them to have.  The problem is they are writing with permission +755 and permission denied when I try to overwrite.

Comment: Have you considered using ACLs?

Comment: have you check into groups, setuid (in directories) or, for changing the permission, changing the umask for those users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the primary group the same for all of these users

```
usermod -g users user1
usermod -g users user2
# (etc)
```

Set the umask for each user to 0002

```
echo 'umask 0002' >> ~user1/.bashrc
echo 'umask 0002' >> ~user2/.bashrc
# (etc)
```

Change ownership of files in existing shared directories

```
find /dat -exec chgrp -R users * \;
find /dat -exec chmod -R g+w * \;
```

Now, files will be created with group "users" and mode 0775. Your users can overwrite each others files.